# JSON respone in list view display based on the particular condition in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to display the items on  particular condition .I done that one.I have three tabs are present.In the first tab A ,i display the list of items,in that only one item is present.But when you move to tab B and again come to tab A,we can see two items.I need to avoid that repeating item displaying, how to do that one, please help me if you have an idea,Thank you in advance
 Here is my code:

```
    List View list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
     ArrayList<String> title_array = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array3 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array4 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array5 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> title_array6 = new ArrayList<String>();
     String response_value;
     JSONObject result;
     JSONArray tokenList;
     JSONObject oj5;
     String appid;
     JSONObject oj;
     String fileid;
     HttpEntity entity;
     String status ,borrowername,coborrowername,loannumber,addrs1,city;

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_frame, container, false);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class


         new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
         return rootView;
        }

        // you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
        public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

            // contacts JSONArray
            JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
          // post the  specific format data to json url
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("Username", "******");
                    object.put("Password", "******");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("Authentication", object);
                    jsonObject.put("RequestType", 4);
                    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("*********");
                    postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
                    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
                 entity = response.getEntity();
                response_value = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
                  //  Log.e(TAG, response_value);

                    if (entity != null) {
                        //Convert String to JSON Object        
                        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response_value); 

                          JSONArray tokenList = result.getJSONArray("Files");


                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return response_value;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response_value) {
                 super.onPostExecute(response_value);
                 // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

                 try
                 {
                      if (entity != null) {
                      result = new JSONObject(response_value);
                      tokenList = result.getJSONArray("Files");
                        for(int i=0;i<=tokenList.length();i++)
                        {
                     oj = tokenList.getJSONObject(i);

                        String oj1 = oj.getString("FileID");
                        JSONObject oj12= (JSONObject) tokenList.getJSONObject(i).get("Borrower");
                        JSONObject oj2 = (JSONObject) tokenList.getJSONObject(i).get("CoBorrower");
                          JSONObject oj3 = (JSONObject) tokenList.getJSONObject(i).get("LoanDetails");
                         JSONObject oj4 = (JSONObject) tokenList.getJSONObject(i).get("PropertyAddress");
                       fileid = oj.getString("FileID");
                        borrowername = oj12.getString("FirstName");
                         coborrowername = oj2.getString("FirstName");
                    loannumber = oj3.getString("LoanNumber");
                    addrs1 = oj4.getString("Address1");
                     city = oj4.getString("City");
                       JSONArray orders = oj.getJSONArray("Orders");

                       for(int n=0;n<orders.length();n++){

                           JSONObject oj5 = orders.getJSONObject(n);

                            appid = oj5.getString("ApplicationOrderId");
                           String duedate = oj5.getString("DueDate");  
                           status = oj5.getString("Status"); 


                         //  Log.e(TAG,  appid +"/"+ appid1);
                           Log.e(TAG, appid + "/" + borrowername + "/"+ coborrowername + "/"+ addrs1 + "/"+ city + "/"+ loannumber + fileid );
                        if(status.equals("1")){
                               title_array3.add("New");
                               title_array1.add(addrs1 + " ,"+ city);
                                title_array.add(borrowername +" , "+coborrowername);
                                title_array2.add("Duedate");
                               // title_array3.add(status);
                                title_array4.add(appid);
                               title_array5.add(loannumber);
                                title_array6.add(fileid);

                            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
                             @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
                             {

                                                                Intent first = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailView.class);
                                first.putExtra("fileid", fileid);
                                startActivity(first);

                                 } });  
                            }   
                        }



                        }
                      } 
                 }

             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
              adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), title_array,title_array1,title_array2,title_array3,title_array4,title_array5,title_array6);
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by when you say page refresh?

Comment: No ,when you refresh the page ,the listview of items is repeating.i want to displaying it is one time only.

Comment: 1) For your first question: how you refresh the page? (what do you do/call to refresh it? )
---- 2) For your second question: you have the last `fileid` because you save his value inside `for(int i=0;i<=tokenList.length();i++)`, so for each iteration you'll overwrite the previous value and in the end you only save the last iteration value.

Comment: how to overcome the overwrite operation

Comment: It's better if you: 1) create a model for your Object (let's say `MyFile.java`). --- 2) Add fields to your class depends on your json object (e.g: `String fileID; Borrower borrower; CoBorrower coBorrower; String firstName; ....`). --- 3) Create a List of this object in your current class (e.g `List<MyFile> mList;`). --- 4) Add item to this list from your json result (inside your loop). ---- 5) `OnItemClickListener` you only need to call `mList.get(position).fileID;` to get the right value.